# Top-down 2D road generation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a top-down/isometric 2D drag racing game in Unity. The idea is that the player is pinned to the left side of the screen, with their x axis locked, and they can only move up and down on the Y axis as the road generates in front of and moves "at" the player. This generation is meant to go on indefinitely as the player's speed increases, until eventually the player crashes into a wall/obstacle. How would I go about generating this road? I tried using [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/146525/making-a-quottrendquot-in-randomly-generated-terra.html) to generate lots of thin slices instead of cubes for my road, but I feel like I'm doing something horribly, horribly wrong.

I can specify a crude drawing of what I want to generate, if that helps.

Yes, I'm a newbie to real projects, I've only done work with simple game mods before, so creating a game from scratch in Unity is a pretty hefty challenge for me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What I've understood is you are looking for an infinite 2d background, which might repeat itself at a point or not. So check [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/scrolling-repeating-backgrounds) scrolling background tutorial from Unity. You can adjust this to your project. Also a picture from your project might help us more to understand it.

Comment: The project is basically completely empty at this point, there's two gameobjects and a script, because this is the very first thing I wanted to do. A repeating background wouldn't work; it has to be a randomly generated road since the entirety of the gameplay is "trying not to run into the walls".

Comment: You can make it random also. If you get the grasp of how the background (or objects) get spawned move towards a place, and another one getting created. Same thing goes on and on. You can create a list/array. Add your objects(road types) in it. Choose one to be generated randomly. So it will not be same always.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but the thing is, I don't want to substitute pre-made road "types" for every section - I'm trying to create a randomly generated infinite runner-type thing, meaning completely the road has to bob and weave up and down on the screen randomly as it gets generated.

Comment: You're always going to have "premade road sections" even if those sections are 1 pixel wide.  All procedurally generated means is that the *order* of those segments is controlled via a procedural process (and need not even involve random numbers at all).